# How export contacts of ubuntu one?

Tags: ubuntu-one

How export contacts of Ubuntu one in 12. 10?

Another questions (possible duplicates) is about old versions, and packages like `evolution-couchdb` are removed in previous versions, thunderbird don't support couchdb.

I can see my contacts in https://one.ubuntu.com/contacts/.

Comment: Separate multiple questions please. Also I don't quite understand which contacts you mean.

Comment: Is only one, how export? ..., i edit for where i see my contacts

Comment: @Konstantin I presume he means the contacts in the Ubuntu One database in Evolution via evolution-couchdb and desktopcouch, the former of which is no longer in Ubuntu 12.10, and the latter of which is removed from Ubuntu 13.04 as well.

Comment: I apologize for posting this as an 'answer' rather than as comments on the answers above, but as a new user it seems I don't have sufficient reputation to do that. The `ubuntuone-addressbook-export.py` script suggested by Roman and [in the Ubuntu One FAQs](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-can-i-export-my-contacts/ "in the Ubuntu One FAQs") appears to hang indefinitely (or at least for 4+ hours) and produces no output. The "little script I just threw together" link from Chipaca leads to a page that reads:
> The Paste you are looking for does not currently exist. Responses to [another AskUbun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a script that creates a vCard file from the data that is stored in Ubuntu One online couchdb. You will need to install `python-vobject` package for it to work.

```
wget http://people.canonical.com/~roman.yepishev/us/bin/ubuntuone-addressbook-export
python ubuntuone-addressbook-export addressbook.vcf
```

The address book entries will be written to `addressbook.vcf`.

Answer (score 3):

For now, the contacts are still backended to CouchDB. This will stop being the case over the next few months (this should get updated when that happens).

What you need to do is [determine the right endpoint for your couchdb instance on the server](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/account_info/cloud), and then query that using the [couchdb REST API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API). As all these requests need to be OAuth-signed, it's not trivial to do; there is [Roman's tool](http://rtg.in.ua/2012/03/18/upload-to-ubuntu-one-using-curl/) that will put the credentials into environment variables you can use to build URLs for `curl` or `wget`, there is a helper `u1oauthrequest` (part of the old `ubuntuone-couch`) that gets your credentials from the keyring, signs the given URL, and prints the result. There is a [little script I just threw together](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1448056/) from scripts used by people on my team.

If you save the latter in a file called `u1couch-backup.py`, you can then call it via

```
python u1couch-backup.py
```

and it should print out the information about your contacts database. If you want to get the list of documents you'd do

```
python u1couch-backup.py /contacts/_all_docs
```

and if you want the actual documents and not just the ids and revnos you'd do

```
python u1couch-backup.py /contacts/_all_docs?include_docs=true
```

The whole thing is quite unreliable to be honest so you might need to retry a couple of times, or retry at a less-busy time, which is why [we flagged it for EOL over a year ago](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-November/003474.html). The move to u1db should make this quite a lot better (soon!), at which point I'll update this answer.

Comment: Note that this will not work if the contents are not synced to U1 (though OP's are). If the contacts are not synced to the U1 server, you'll need to pull them out of the local couchdb. You can do this even if they are synced as well. With desktopcouch-service (and it's instance of couchdb) started up and running, you can open the HTML file in ~/.local/share/desktopcouch/ in a browser to access the Futon interface to couchdb. You should be able to find your contacts entries in there as well.

Comment: good point @dobey. work it into the answer?